# Sentimental Analysis of review comments using qdap is slow

Tags: r, shiny, sentiment-analysis, qdap

Am using **qdap** package to determine the sentiment of each review comment of a particular application. I read the review comments from a CSV file and pass it to the polarity function of qdap. Everything works fine and I get the polarity for all the review comments but the problem is that it takes 7-8 seconds to calculate the polarity all the sentences (total number of sentences present in the CSV file is 779). I am pasting my code below.

```
  temp_csv <- filePath()
  attach(temp_csv)
  text_data <- temp_csv[,c('Content')]
  print(Sys.time())
  polterms <- list(neg=c('wtf'))
  POLKEY <- sentiment_frame(positives=c(positive.words),negatives=c(polterms[[1]],negative.words))     
  polarity <- polarity(sentences, polarity.frame = POLKEY) 
  print(Sys.time())
```

Time taken is as follows:

[1] "2016-04-12 16:43:01 IST"

[1] "2016-04-12 16:43:09 IST"

Can somebody let me know if I am doing something wrong?
How can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I am the author of **qdap**.  The `polarity` function was designed for much smaller data sets.  As my role shifted I began to work with larger data sets.  I needed fast and accurate (these two things are in opposition to each other) and have since developed a break away package [sentimentr](https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr#comparing-sentimentr-syuzhet-and-stanford).  The algorithm is optimized to be faster and more accurate than **qdap**'s polarity.

As it stands now you have 5 dictionary based (or trained alorithm based) approached to sentiment detection.  Each has it's drawbacks (-) and pluses (+) and is useful in certain circumstances.

1. [qdap](https://github.com/trinker/qdap)  +on CRAN; -slow
2. [syuzhet](https://github.com/mjockers/syuzhet) +on CRAN; +fast; +great plotting; -less accurate on non-literature use
3. [sentimentr](https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr) +fast; +higher accuracy; -GitHub only
4. [stansent (stanford port)](https://github.com/trinker/stansent) +most accurate; -slower
5. [tm.plugin.sentiment](https://github.com/mannau/tm.plugin.sentiment) -archived on CRAN; -I couldn't get it working easily

I show time tests on sample data for the first 4 choices from above in the code below.

## Install packages and make timing functions

I use pacman because it allows the reader to just run the code; though you can replace with `install.packages` & `library` calls.

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(qdap, syuzhet, dplyr)
pacman::p_load_current_gh(c("trinker/stansent", "trinker/sentimentr"))

pres_debates2012 #nrow = 2912

tic <- function (pos = 1, envir = as.environment(pos)){
    assign(".tic", Sys.time(), pos = pos, envir = envir)
    Sys.time()
}

toc <- function (pos = 1, envir = as.environment(pos)) {
    difftime(Sys.time(), get(".tic", , pos = pos, envir = envir))
}

id <- 1:2912
```

## Timings

```
## qdap
tic()
qdap_sent <- pres_debates2012 %>%
    with(qdap::polarity(dialogue, id))
toc() # Time difference of 18.14443 secs


## sentimentr
tic()
sentimentr_sent <- pres_debates2012 %>%
    with(sentiment(dialogue, id))
toc() # Time difference of 1.705685 secs


## syuzhet
tic()
syuzhet_sent <- pres_debates2012 %>%
    with(get_sentiment(dialogue, method="bing"))
toc() # Time difference of 1.183647 secs


## stanford
tic()
stanford_sent <- pres_debates2012 %>%
    with(sentiment_stanford(dialogue))
toc() # Time difference of 6.724482 mins
```

For more on timings and accuracy see my [sentimentr README.md](https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr#comparing-sentimentr-syuzhet-and-stanford) and please **star the repo if it's useful**.  The viz below captures one of the tests from the README:

[image]

Comment: I agree with Tyler, I have had good results with syuzhet on very large sets of snippet/review sized text chunks.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler Rinker for the detailed analysis of various sentiment packages. Just now checked out the sentimentr package created by you. This is exactly what I needed. But I need the list of positive words and negative words from each sentence. I was getting this while using qdap where as sentimentr returns only the word count. Is it possible to get them while using sentimentr?

Comment: @VenuSathya20 no it didn't make sense to me any more.  Can I ask what you'd want to do with them?

Comment: @Tyler Rinker apologies for the delay in the response. I was using those words (positive and negative words separately) to form positive and negative word clouds.

Comment: @VenuSathya20 The `extract_sentiment_terms` function in sentimentr will give you the terms but is run as a separate function.  This keeps the main `sentiment` function speedy.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am unable to use stansent (stanford port) part as it is either not supported by the R 3.4.1 otherwise i am missing something. I hope someone could write some detailed description about using this from scratch on windows.